# Prevent c++ template codes from being compiled for many times

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, explicit-instantiation, translation-unit

I coded a message queue template in c++, and I want use it in many different projects, so that I put it into a namespace, for example `my_lib`.

In order to prevent the codes from being compiled repeatedly, I used a separate trans-unit to explicitly instantiate it(and get only one obj file), and merely include its header every where involving it.

But where it being used, is in another namespace for example `business`.

The skeleton of my codes looks like the followings:

mq-template.hpp:

```
#pragma once
namespace my_lib {
template<typename T, typename SIZE_TYPE>
class GenericMQ_t {
    struct Node_t {
        SIZE_TYPE _head;
        SIZE_TYPE _tail;
        T         _data;
    };
    SIZE_TYPE _size {};
    Node_t*   _buff {};
public:
    void send( const T& );
};
}; // namespace my_lib
```

mq-template.tpp(mind the suffix):

```
#include "mq-template.hpp"
namespace my_lib {
template<typename T, typename SIZE_TYPE>
void GenericMQ_t<T, SIZE_TYPE>::send( const T& ) {
    // just for example
    std::cout << "Hello!";
};
}; // namespace my_lib
```

mq-instance.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "mq-template.hpp"
namespace business {
struct Msg_t {};
using RealMQ_t = my_lib::GenericMQ_t<Msg_t, int>;
}; // namespace business
```

mq-instance.cpp:

```
#include "mq-instance.hpp"
#include "mq-template.tpp"
namespace business {
template class my_lib::GenericMQ_t<Msg_t, int>;
}; // namespace business
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mq-instance.hpp"
int main() {
    business::Msg_t    msg;
    business::RealMQ_t mq;
    mq.send( msg );
    return 0;
}
```

When `mq-instance.cpp` was compiling, I got some error like this:

> explicit instantiation of 'class my_lib::GenericMQ_t<business::Msg_t,
> int>' in namespace 'business' (which does not enclose namespace
> 'my_lib') [-fpermissive]
>
> explicit instantiation of 'struct
> my_lib::GenericMQ_t<business::Msg_t, int>::Node_t' in namespace
> 'business' (which does not enclose namespace 'my_lib') [-fpermissive]

It is impossible to put my all codes into a same namespace, because they belongs to different projects, and eventhough in a same project, the naming schema may be hierarchical.

How should I modify my code, let it satisfy both of:

1. The template codes should not be compiled for many times;
2. The template codes and instantiating codes may sit in different
   namespaces;

Sorry for my ugly English.

Comment: You can't/shouldn't. Namespaces are designed to prevent coincidental usage of names in one namespace from other namespace.

Comment: 1. What stops you from moving `template class my_lib::GenericMQ_t<Msg_t, int>;` outside of the namespace? 2. You also need `extern template class my_lib::GenericMQ_t<Msg_t, int>;` in the header.

Comment: @user12002570 It will work in the global namespace.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Right, enclosing namespace can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the explicit instantiation to the enclosing namespace(which is global namespace) as shown below.

**mq-instance.cpp**

```
#include "mq-instance.hpp"
#include "mq-template.tpp"

template class my_lib::GenericMQ_t<business::Msg_t, int>; //in global namespace
namespace business {  

};
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ta-pX6J3-)

Answer (score 2):

You are making things to complicated.
To prevent template instantiation every time it is used you can use this:

```cpp
extern template my_lib::GenericMQ_t<business::Msg_t, int>;
```

Then in some cpp file ti enforce instantiation of template you can do:

```cpp
template my_lib::GenericMQ_t<business::Msg_t, int>;
```

So first thing you can place below your template definition in `mq-template.hpp`
and second thing in `mq-template.cpp`. No need to play with other files.

[Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template).

Comment: Thanks!  I think that your solution is very clean and graceful too!  But I want not only to reduce compiling time, but also put the instance into namespace `business`.  Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a pity that you can't move up and down in scopes like you can in Linux, I mean `cd ../currentScope and cd currentScope/nextScope` but it's interesting that this solution might work in your code.

**mq-instance.cpp**

```
namespace my_lib {
    template class GenericMQ_t<::business::Msg_t, int>;
}; // namespace my_lib
```